# Wordpress Bootstrap Navwalker Driving Me Bonkers

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

Having trouble getting the navwalker to expand on mobile.

I have added the code to functions php

```html
// Register Custom Bootstrap Navigation Walker
require_once get_template_directory() . '/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
```

Here is my navwalker code, if anyone can help me resolve this conundrum I would be most greatful. Please excuse the formatting on here.

```html
 <nav class="main-menu navbar navbar-bg thetop" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">     
     <?php if (function_exists('the_custom_logo')) {
      the_custom_logo();
     }
     else{
       bloginfo('name');
      }
     ?>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
     'theme_location'    => 'primary',
     'depth'             => 2,
     'container'         => 'div',
     'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
     'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
     'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
     'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
     'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
    );
    ?>
   </ul>
   <!-- Search Form -->
   <form id="searchform" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" placeholder="Ara"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary -red"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
     
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-top-cta affirmation hidden-xs hidden-sm"></a>
   </form>

  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured this out. I am building a new theme using wpBootstrapStarter. Recently updated the theme which also updated bootstrap release using jquery 3.3.2. I just downgraded and all is well.

I guess the devs didn't fully test before release. Good job i spotted via console.